Large deviations for automorphisms of Erdős–Rényi
Let $p\ggg \frac{\log(n)}n$ and $1-p\ggg \frac{\log(n)}n$ and $G(n,p)$ be the Erdős–Rényi random graph. The parameter is chosen such that $G(n,p)$ and its complement don't have isolated vertices, and a classical result says that $\text{Aut}(G(n,p))$ is the trivial group with high probability.
This question asks for $\mathbb E[|\text{Aut}(G(n,p))|]$. There's an accepted answer but unfortunately I don't think it really answers the question. The automorphism group can very rarely be as large as $n!$, so it's not clear the expectation is even bounded.
I think this question is hard, so I'd like to ask for $p=\frac 12$ or whichever $p=p(n)$ in the given interval is easiest to work with:

What is $\mathbb P[|\text{Aut}(G(n,p))|>k]$ asymptotically for $k=k(n)$ and $n\to\infty$?

If I pick some wacky group, say the Mathieu group $M_{23}$, what is $\mathbb P[\text{Aut}(G(n,p))=M_{23}]$ asymptotically?

What are the most common groups that $\text{Aut}(G)$ can be other than the trivial one? More precisely, for a fixed group $G$ what is $\mathbb P[\text{Aut}(G(n,p)=G|\:|\text{Aut}(G(n,p))|=|G|]$?

A particular case of the above: what is $\mathbb P[\text{Aut}(G(n,p))\text{ is not abelian}|\: |\text{Aut}(G(n,p))|>1 ]$?



For various reasons I think a more natural question is going to end up being to ask about the inverse of the size of the automorphism group (the "groupoid cardinality"). This behaves less violently when the graph acquires more symmetry, for example.

After the trivial group, the most common group is the $2$-element group, which occurs with probability around $n^2/2^n$. But many of your questions seem much harder to answer than the original. I think a reasonable line of attack for $\mathbb E[|\text{Aut}(G(n,p))|]$ is linearity of expectation over all $n!$ permutations of the vertices. First argue that a permutation that moves more than (idk, maybe $\log n$?) vertices around has a probability of $\ll \frac1{n!}$ of being an automorphism, then deal with the remaining few cases more carefully.
